# Issue with Nant and Nunit2

Tags: c#, nunit, nant

I'm getting this error trying to execute my tests using nunit2 task

> Failure executing test(s). If you assembly is not built using NUnit version 2.6.0.12051, then ensure you have redirected assembly bindings

The nunit version for my test project is 2.6.2.12296.

I tested several redirect bindings on my test project config file but nothing did the trick. I know I could use `EXEC` to run nunit.exe directly instead of using nunit2 task but I'd like to make this work.

**UPDATE**

This is my current app.config for the testing project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d0234a77" culture="Neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.0.12051" newVersion="2.6.2.12296" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is the relevant part of the build file

```
<nunit2>
  <test 
    assemblyname="D:\[the full path]\UnitTests.dll" 
    appconfig="D:\customTest.config"/>
  <formatter type="Plain"/>
</nunit2>
```

Comment: does this error happen also when you start debug your project?

Comment: @giammin: no, this error only happen when running nant

Comment: could you post your nant .build file

Answer (score 3):

When you use NAnt NUnit2 tasks if the version of your test framework does not match with the version NAnt was built with you have to tell NAnt NUnit2 tasks to use binding redirect.

The problem is that NUnit test runner creates a new AppDomain for each test so you can't do a binding redirect with the app.config of the testing project.

You have to create a custom config file with the binding redirect:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d0234a77" culture="Neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.2.12051" newVersion="2.6.2.12296" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

And tell NUnit2 NAnt task to use it:

```
<nunit2>
    <test assemblyname="ProjectName.Tests.dll" appconfig="customTest.config" />
     ...
</nunit2>
```

--------------**Last thought**------------------------------

your config is:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.0.12051" newVersion="2.6.2.12296" />
```

try with

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.2.12296" newVersion="2.6.2.12296" />
```

and double check if all external references of your test project are `copy local=true` in visualstudio properties window

Comment: Where do I have to place that custom app config file?

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool where do you prefere, then you reference it with appconfig="c:\yoursolution\customTest.config"

Comment: I did this but I'm getting the same error. There is something weird though: no matter what config file path set it never complains about not finding the file even when I put an incorrect path. I wonder if is honoring that setting, it seems it's not paying attention to it or failing in silence in case the file is not found.

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool check if xml elements and attributes are in lowercase appconfig not appConfig

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool or try to move the customTest.config in the test dll folder and delete others .config files. This must be a trivial error or mispelling somewhere

Comment: no luck :( nant is a very frustrating tool. It could be me though. Thanks for your help man +1

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool I agree, nant is very tedious to use... hope you find a solution! let as know

Comment: Sorry for the delay, no luck. I'll use the EXEC strategy after all, I don't like very much but this is not working at all :( thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add `<bindingRedirect>`  to your .config as described in [NUnit documenation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/nunit2.html):

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d0234a77" culture="Neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.2.12051" newVersion="2.6.2.12296" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Or use Nant `<exec>` like:

```
 <exec program="${LibraryPath}\NUnit\2.6.2\nunit-console.exe">
   <arg value="${SourcePath}\ProjectName.Tests\bin\Release\ProjectName.Tests.dll" />
 </exec>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I've already tested that and didn't work :( I know I can use `exec` but I'm trying to avoid that. Thanks!

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool if you have already tested **bindingRedirect** before my answer - why havent you show it in your question under what you have done? It will save the time for the users who try to help you =)

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool the other part is about **<exec>** Its may work but you dont like it? Than again why didnt you said you your question "please withou <exex>"?

Comment: please read the question again, since the beggining I said that I tested several redirect bindings without luck and I also said that I want to avoid using exec :) I should've specifified which redirects I tried though. I apologize about that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My solution was to change the platform from x86 to Any CPU.
It seems that nunit has problems with different platforms.

Greets